# How to get a new refresh token after it expires?

Tags: provider-hosted-app

How to get a new refresh token after it expires?
We have a scenarios in provider-hosted app which require to cache the refresh token in db, and we were reusing it to generate client context. It was working fine, but it got expired after 6 months and getting **Token request failed. (400) Bad Request.**

How to get a new refresh token after it expires? It is possible to renew token from existing token ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn762763.aspx#RefreshTokens

Comment: This used to happen earlier  when solely using TohenHelper class. That is why Microsoft introduced a new class for Provider hosted apps called SharePointContext. This class handles the tokens. Read more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps.aspx